# Should I use include(_once) or require(_once) for loading php-file with customizer settings?

Tags: php, include, template-include

Should I use include, include_once, require or require_once to load my customizer.php file? That file has all customizer settings and code in it. What is your advice on this?

The file is currently being loaded with include() in the functions.php.

And can I use a fallback? For all situations that I can't predict, when the customizer.php file fails to load?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a WP question, it sounds like a question about basic PHP, it might be better to ask this on StackOverflow. Otherwise if your code requires the things in that file, `require` it

Comment: Well, I would say that customizer settings are always required. Shouldn't I use require_once then? I asked the question for advice from WP developers, because they would know the customizer and the importance of it. Therefore I asked it here and not on Stackoverflow.